# Using multiple SSL on multiple domains using one IP address

Tags: apache2, ssl

I'm using Apache and I have two domains which I've created virtual hosts for and installed SSL certificates.  However only one domain works and the other just redirects to this domain.  I think this is because site one is the primary site and I need a separate IP address for each domain when using SSL?

I've read quite a few articles that say you can use multiple SSL certificates with one IP by doing the following in your virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
```

I've tried this but it doesn't work for me.  Also a lot of articles mention SNI but I'm not 100% sure what this means.  Could someone shed some light on this and point me in the right direction?

This is what my virtual hosts look like

**Site 1**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin email@gmail.com
  ServerName  domain.com
  ServerAlias www.domain.com

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain.com/public_html
  Redirect permanent / https://www.domain.com

  <Directory "/var/www/html/domain.com/public_html">
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  </Directory>

  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  #ErrorLog  /var/www/html/domain.com/log/error.log
  #CustomLog /var/www/html/domain.com/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin email@gmail.com
        ServerName domain.com
        ServerAlias www.domain.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain.com/public_html
        <Directory "/var/www/html/domain.com/public_html">
                #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined

        Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
        <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
                Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Order deny,allow
                Deny from all
                Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
        </Directory>

        #   SSL Engine Switch:
        #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
        SSLEngine on

        #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
        #   the ssl-cert package. See
        #   /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/README.Debian.gz for more info.
        #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
        #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
        SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/www_domain_com/www_domain_com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/www_domain_com/server.key

        #   Server Certificate Chain:
        #   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
        #   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
        #   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
        #   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
        #   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
        #   certificate for convinience.
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/www_domain_com/www_domain_com.ca-bundle

        #...

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**Site 2**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin email@gmail.com
  ServerName  domain2.com
  ServerAlias www.domain2.com

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain2.com/public_html/public
  #  Redirect permanent / https://www.domain2.com

  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/www/html/domain2.com/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/html/domain2.com/log/access.log combined

  SetEnv CI_ENV production
  SetEnv CI_BASE_URL http://www.domain2.com/

  <Directory "/var/www/html/domain2.com/public_html/public">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Content"
        AuthUserFile /var/www/html/domain2.com/public_html/public/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user

        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin email@gmail.com
        ServerName domain2.com
        ServerAlias www.domain2.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain2.com/public_html/public

        <Directory "/var/www/html/domain2.com/public_html/public">
                #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

       ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/

        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined
        Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"

        <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
                Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Order deny,allow
                Deny from all
                Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
        </Directory>

        #   SSL Engine Switch:
        #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
        SSLEngine on

        #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
        #   the ssl-cert package. See
        #   /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/README.Debian.gz for more info.
        #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
        #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
        SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/www_domain2_com/www_domain2_com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/www_domain2_com/server.key

        #   Server Certificate Chain:
        #   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
        #   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
        #   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
        #   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
        #   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
        #   certificate for convinience.
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/www_domain2_com/www_domain2_com.ca-bundle

        #...

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Could you show us the content of your.domain.conf files?

Comment: @SpasSpasov Updated

Comment: As redundant as it is, put up the second one as well.  Making sure domain is changed to domain2, or something to indicate where everything is set.  It could be something simple like they are both pointing to the same directory.  I see no reason it wouldn't work otherwise.

Comment: @bc2946088 Added it

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an IP per ssl domain, but you do need the ServerName directive in each virtualhost.  The following should work using apache2.  It will be slightly different if you are not using apache2.

---

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www

</VirtualHost>


<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www

        #   SSL Engine Switch:
        #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
        SSLEngine on

        #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
        #   the ssl-cert package. See
        #   /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/README.Debian.gz for more info.
        #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
        #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com/apache.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com/apache.key
</VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
```

Comment: This does work in the sense that it gives no errors but site 2 is still getting redirected to site 1.  Do you know what might be causing this?

Comment: Did you restart apache after updating the configuration?  Have you enabled the ssl module?

Comment: Yep done that, I've checked the apache error log and everything is okay.  I think it's to do with the first site being the default?

Comment: Disable the config it's finding first to make sure the second can be loaded.  `sudo a2dissite site.domain.conf`, probably want to update your question with your configs redacting any personal information.

Comment: Okay updated question.  I disabled site one but it was still redirecting to it which means it's somehow the default

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Configuration applying only to one of multiple sites belongs into the site's config.

move

```
<Directory /var/www/html/example.com>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory> 
ServerName example.com
```

from

> **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

into

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.conf
```

Comment: Note: clear browser cache / history to test.